# SSH tunneling over cloudflare tunnel for linux server

Tags: ssh, dns, vpn, ssh-tunneling, tunneling

I need to connect to my linux server over cloudflare tunnel to protect my server. I have some user and need it for this. can every one help my?

I tried this commands:

```
mkdir Argo && cd Argo

wget https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflared/releases/download/2023.10.0/cloudflared-linux-amd64 && chmod +x cloudflared-linux-amd64

./cloudflared-linux-amd64 tunnel login

./cloudflared-linux-amd64 tunnel create

./cloudflared-linux-amd64 tunnel route dns

tmux

./cloudflared-linux-amd64 tunnel --url localhost:9443 run
```